# Azure CLI query into specific folder

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Is there a way to search for file at a specific location instead of searching through an entire container? I have this query running on Azure CLI but it searches for specific patterns in the entire container and issue I am facing is after a while, query just freezes over. I have tried several ways but nothing works. Here is the query that runs fine for an hour and then gives me a nextMarker that will not continue the search. (Did I maximize my quote of search on Azure?) Please take a look and let me know what you think.

```
container_name=pure3
numResults=1000
marker=---some value----
az storage blob list \
       --account-name $account_name \
       --account-key $key \
       --num-results $numResults \
       --show-next-marker \
       --container-name $container_name \
       --prefix "pure3/fastqs/170707_" \ \
       --marker $marker \
       --query "[[].name, [].nextMarker]" --output yamlc
```

and I have this Shell script that continue the search one after another.

```
#/usr/bin/

./Azure_Search_newQ.sh > out

tail -1 out
line=$(tail -1 out);
echo "Length is:${#line}"
expr=${line:4:${#line}}
echo $expr

head -n -1 out >>Blob_Files
while [ ! -z "$expr" ]
do
        sed "s/FLAG/${expr}/g" Azure_listBlob_wMarker_FLAG.sh > Azure_Search_newQ.sh
        chmod +x Azure_Search_newQ.sh
        ./Azure_Search_newQ.sh > out
        head -n -1 out >>Blob_Files
        line=$(tail -1 out)
        echo "Length is:${#line}"
        expr=${line:4:${#line}}
        echo $expr
done
```

I tried running the code after 24 hrs and use the nextMarker that was stuck in the last run, same result.
I tried starting my run from 2 previous nextMarker and it ran fine and got stuck on the same nextMarker.

So far, I have searched through 1076000 files.

Here is the snapshot of azure cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

To search for blobs in a particular folder inside a container, please use `—-prefix` parameter and specify the folder name there.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-list):

```bash
az storage blob list -c mycontainer --prefix foo
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the post with your suggestion but still getting no results. I am running single code to search in that folder but it returns without any results.

Comment: Prefix doesn't work that way. In your case (based on your screenshot), you will need to specify `prefix` as `pure3/fastqs/`.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, Yea I tried that. I edited the original post to include the snapshot of my azure explorer location and then the script. It still returns empty but it should show me the file that is there... Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the name of your container?

Comment: this works for me. 
az storage blob list --account-name <accountname> --account-key <key> --container-name <name> --prefix <folder path> | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object { $_.name.EndsWith(".txt") } | ConvertTo-Json

Answer (score 0):

> Azure CLI query into specific folder

I do agree with @alex, I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-list):

```
az storage blob list --account-name "name of storage account" --container-name "name of the container" --account-key "RqOU/00Q+p6CRj2kvF/FVb3bP3X+AStV19sEg==" --prefix Nameoffolder/
```

**Output:**

[image]

Also if you want all file names in a folder you can use:

```
 $x=az storage blob list --account-name "rithwikstorage" --container-name "rithwik" --account-key "RqOU1A6rGSaRWEu42IOVb3bP3X+AStV19sEg==" --prefix EmoFolder/ | ConvertFrom-Json
 $x.name
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Surya but so far I haven't received any solution to my problem. I will accept as soon as I will get one. My code is still suffering from same issue as it was before the post.

Comment: Hey @Priyank Shukla Have you tried my code? I have got desired outputs as you have mentioned

Comment: yes your code does work but the real issue is not the right code but why my code works for one hour, produce whatever I ask it to do and then hangs after an hour. I think there is internal switch on Azure cloud explorer that terminates any query after a certain number of attempts or time. Since I am not getting the end of my blob list so when code stops, I am not sure whether my code ended that's why file is not there or genuinely it is not there. Is there anyway to find it out or go around this?